# Android: Bitcoin J INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113

Tags: android, android-studio, java-native-interface, web3js, bitcoinj

I am facing an issue with my Project Everything was working fine before I Integrated **BitcoinJ** Library, Once I add that library to my Gradle file it stops installing the APK on ***Real Device*** with the error:

> INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries,
>   res=-113

Here is My Gradle File:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.umerkiani.osrwallet"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dataBinding {
    enabled true
}



compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}


}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'org.bitcoinj:bitcoinj-core:0.14.7'
implementation('org.web3j:core:3.3.1-android')

}
```

I have also tried adding the following lines to Gradle but it didn't Help

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86_64'
        universalApk true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use follwing in app.gradle it will resolve your issue

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.umerkiani.osrwallet"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'lib/x86_64/darwin/libscrypt.dylib'
        exclude 'lib/x86_64/freebsd/libscrypt.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86_64/linux/libscrypt.so'
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'org.bitcoinj:bitcoinj-core:0.14.7'
    implementation('org.web3j:core:3.3.1-android')
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.1'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:5.0.0'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0'
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rootProject.rxandroidVersion"
}
```